# Having issues writing to a JSON file, after reading it (discord.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I've been working on a project for a friend's discord server, where I want to keep sort of a 'database' on our members, like a warning (or strike) count, their age (because we've been having issues with underage members) and some notes.  I've been using tutorials as I'm pretty new to javascript, and really new to Discord.js, so, I'm not really sure on what I'm doing yet.

(to clarify, I'm not getting any errors, it's just not updating to the new file)

Here are the resources I've used:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JB1rWJRafRA

https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/collectors.html#message-collectors

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J2bKyv5pp-M

And my code:  (sorry in advance, it's really messy)

````js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const fs = require('fs');
const jsonfile = require('jsonfile');
const Client = new Discord.Client();

var data = {}; //start of member activeness tracker
if (fs.existsSync('data.json')) {
    data = jsonfile.readFileSync('data.json');
}

console.log("Bot Starting...");

Client.on("ready", () => console.log('ServerMgr is ready!  Now managing servers!'));  //bot init complete

Client.on("message", (message) =>  {

    if (message.guild.id in data === false) {data[message.guild.id] = {} } //if new guild

    const guildData = data[message.guild.id];

    if (message.author.id in guildData === false) {
        guildData[message.author.id] = {
            username: message.author.username,
            message_count: 0,
            last_message: 0,
            age: 0,
            times_left: 0,
            strikes: 0,
            notes: ""
         }
    }

    const userData = guildData[message.author.id];
    userData.message_count ++
    userData.last_message = Date.now();

    jsonfile.writeFileSync('data.json', data)

    const parts = message.content.split(' ') 
    if(parts[0] === ';ping') {message.reply('```SeverMgr is online!\nCurrent Ping: ' + (Math.abs(Date.now() - message.createdTimestamp))/ 100 + " ms```")}
    if(parts[0] === ';read') {
        if (message.mentions.members.first()) {
            var user = message.mentions.users.first()
            const id = user.id
            const userData = guildData[id]
            const lastMessage = new Date(userData.last_message)
            message.channel.send("Getting data for " + user.username + "#" + user.discriminator + "...")
            message.channel.send("Sent " + userData.message_count + " messages\n" + 
            "Last message was sent at: " + lastMessage + "\n" +
            "Age: " + userData.age + "\n" + 
            "Times user left server: " + userData.times_left + "\n" +
            "Strikes: " + userData.strikes + "\n" + 
            userData.notes);

        } else {
        message.reply("You need to mention a user to get their data!");
        }
    }

    if(parts[0] === ';write') {
        if (message.mentions.members.first()) {

            var user = message.mentions.users.first();
            const id = user.id;
            const userData = guildData[id];

            message.channel.send("What data point do you want to edit? \n Accepted responses are: \n `message count` \n `age` \n `times left` \n `strikes` \n `notes` ")
            let filter = m => m.content.includes('message count' || 'age' || 'times left' || 'strikes' || 'notes') && !m.author.bot ;
            let collector = new Discord.MessageCollector(message.channel, filter);

    collector.on('collect', (m,col) => {
        var res = "";
        let mess = m.content;
        console.log(mess);
        if (mess == ("message count")) {res = 'message_count' } 
        if (mess == ("age")) {res = 'age' }
        if (mess == ("times left")) {res = 'times_left' }
        if (mess == ("strikes")) {res = 'strikes' }
        if (mess == ("notes")) {res = 'notes' }
        console.log(res);
        message.channel.send("Editing " + res + "\n The current value is:");

        if (res == "message count") {message.channel.send(userData.message_count) } 
        if (res == "age") {message.channel.send(userData.age)}
        if (res == "times left") {message.channel.send(userData.times_left)}
        if (res == "strikes") {message.channel.send(userData.strikes)}
        if (res == "notes") {message.channel.send(userData.notes)}

        collector.stop();
        message.channel.send("The value currently located inside of " + res + " will be overwritten, so if you want to edit the content directly, copy the message above, and paste it into the send box.");
        let filter = m => !m.author.bot;
        let collector2 = new Discord.MessageCollector(message.channel, filter);
    });

    collector2.on('collect', m => {
        var mess = m.content;
        if (res === "message count") {userData.message_count = mess } 
        if (res == "age") {userData.age = mess}
        if (res == "times left") {userData.times_left = mess}
        if (res == "strikes") {userData.strikes = mess}
        if (res == "notes") {userData.notes = mess}
        message.channel.send("Data saved!");
        console.log("Saving " + mess);
    
        var guildData = data[message.guild.id];
        var userData = guildData[message.author.id];
        var pointData = userData[res];
        console.log("old data");
        console.log(pointData);
        pointData = mess;
        console.log("new data");
        console.log(pointData);
        jsonfile.writeFileSync('data.json', data) //HERE IS THE ISSUE
        collector2.stop();
    });

    } else {
        message.reply("You need to mention a user to edit their data!");
    }
}
});

Client.login('TOKEN');
````

The data is stored as such:

```json
'779904676879007744': {
    username: 'SeverMgr',
    message_count: 129,
    last_message: 1606028233445,
    age: 0,
    times_left: 0,
    strikes: 0,
    notes: ''
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Can you specify the issues you have with the JSON? Any error messages?

Comment: What does the error say?

Comment: I haven't gotten any errors, it's just not updating the file.

Comment: Does the code block run? Do you see the console.log above?

Comment: Yes, all the console.logs show up in the log.

Comment: Have you made sure that the data variable is populated with new data? So it's not just replacing it with the same data in the file? Maybe print data before saving etc.

Is the .json populated at all? or just not with the new data?

Comment: The data variable is populated, but not with the new data.

Comment: I see, then your problem must be further up in the code. I don't see you adding the data from mess to data. That might be your issue.

Comment: Okay, I just figured you were able to "tree" the variable like I did further up the code. Data > Guild Data > User Data.   I am directly editing userData, and it works, I just don't understand why I can't directly edit pointerData and it updates the Data variable.

Comment: It's a copy of userData. Not a reference to it.

Comment: That makes a lot more sense. Thanks for the help!

Comment: No problem, I added an answer with an example which you could accept :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equal sign will create a copy of your variable. If you update the new variable it won't update the value of the previous one, since it's not a reference.
Example

```
var x = 1
var y = x
var y = 2
---
x will still be 1
y will be 2
```

So in your case you could do this to update the data variable

```js
data[message.guild.id][message.author.id][res] = mess
```

Instead of this, since you are updating copies and not data directly.

```js
var guildData = data[message.guild.id]
var userData = guildData[message.author.id]
var pointData = userData[res]
pointData = mess
```